# How could I get the text defining an Excel formula for one cell into another cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2003

In other words, if the value of a cell, say A1, is `=Date()`, then displayed in cell A1 I will see the date, but then I want B1 to be `=FuncText(A1)`, then I want to see 'Date()' displayed in cell B1.

To emphasize, I want to see the text 'Date()', i.e. the six chars ending with a ')' in B1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `B1` Cell, write **`=A1`**

So you will see the **A1** Cell Date in **B1** Cell too

Updated as per your information:-

```
Function FuncText(fma As Range) 
    If fma.HasFormula Then 
        FuncText = fma.Formula 
    Else: FuncText = fma 
    End If 
End Function
```

## Output:

On **B1** Cell, returns as **"=Date()"**

But if you want exactly as **"Date()"** then use below function

```
Function FuncText(fma As Range)
    If fma.HasFormula Then
        FuncText = Mid(fma.Formula, 2, Len(fma.Formula))
    Else: FuncText = Mid(fma, 2, Len(fma))
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: You misunderstand me, I want to see the text 'Date()', i.e. the six chars ending with a ')' in B1.

Comment: updated my answer, as per your update.

Answer (score 1):

Quick & simple.  You'll need to make a user-defined function to do this... but it's do-able:

http://dmcritchie.mvps.org/excel/formula.htm

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.